# Correct web user for PHP-FPM under Nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, owner

I've always been accustomed to running PHP under Nginx as the `www-data` user, for everything: php service, cron, CLI, etc. Recently though, after reading up on firstly [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04) and then [this article](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/before/before-workspace-file-sys-owner.html), I'd like to know how necessary it is to run these services using a different user? This is for a single Magento 2 application on the server.

Is it sufficient to create a new user:

```
adduser magento2user
passwd magento2user

usermod -a -G www-data magento2user
```

Then in php `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
[www]  
user = magento2user
group = magento2user
...
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

And then finally:

```
chown -R magento2user:www-data /var/www/html
```

My confusion is coming from this on the [Magento 2 DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html):

> We recommend two users if you run your own Magento server: one to transfer files and run command-line utilities, and a separate user for the web server software. When possible, this is preferable because it’s more secure.
>
> Instead, you have separate users:
>
> • The web server user, which runs the Magento Admin (including Setup Wizard) and storefront.
>
> • A command-line user, which is a local user account you can use to log in to the server. This user runs Magento cron jobs and command-line utilities.

So by this, should PHP-FPM be run as `www-data`, but the files be owned by `magento2user` who belongs to the `www-data` group?

---

**EDIT after Simon Greenwood's answer below**

If I run `ps aux | grep nginx | grep -v grep` I get the following output:

```
1 www-data   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
7 www-data   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

... so I don't think I need an entry in `'etx/nginx/nginx.conf` that reads `user www-data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to recommend running `nginx` as the system user, so `www-data` in your case, and `php-fpm` as a non-privileged user, which can be the same as the shell user. You don't have to have your non-privileged user in the `www-data` group as `nginx` passes requests to `php-fpm`. for execution. The setup suggested by the Magento docs assumes `apache` and `mod_php`, which would require the permissions setup as described above.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  So would you suggest that I leave my php-fpm `www.conf` as is then?

Comment: I would be inclined to do it as you have described above, you're not then exposing your application files to the system.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Please see my edit above. So just to confirm ... leave Nginx running as `www-data` user, run PHP-FPM as `magento2user` as per my `www.conf` configuration above, but don't add `magento2user` to the `www-data` group

Comment: That should do it.